# RobotFramework + SwingLibrary: Tests don't work over SSH

Tags: java, swing, ssh, vagrant, robotframework

This is a painful problem. I've got a Java Swing app that I'm trying to test using Robot Framework with SwingLibrary. I'm doing everything in a Vagrant box. I've got a run script like so that will start the test:

```
export CLASSPATH=swinglibrary-1.8.0.jar:echoapp.jar
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"
jython `which robot` --loglevel DEBUG test.robot
```

This script works totally fine when I run it in the VM. But if I run it over SSH, I can't get it to work properly. I see the following error message:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/vagrant/robotTests/test.robot': Getting keyword 
names from library 'SwingLibrary' failed: Calling dynamic method 
'getKeywordNames' failed: ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I'm totally confused. I initially thought it was an X11 issue, but then I turned on X11 forwarding, connected into the Vagrant box with Putty, and got the application to come up in an X11 Window.

Googling for the error hasn't been super helpful. Anything, anyone? I'm hurting pretty bad on this issue.

Comment: is the machine on which the jython process is running also have the swing library installed?

Comment: Yep. I can log into the VM using the VirtualBox GUI, and run the script. The VM has jython, robot framework, and swing library installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, here's what my problem was. Despite setting up X11 forwarding, the X server wasn't cooperating. Since I'm preparing to run these tests in Jenkins anyhow, that wasn't going to help me in the long run--I was going to need an alternative X Server.

Fortunately, I'm not the first person to try GUI testing. As it turns out, there's an X Server designed for use on headless systems called X Virtual Frame Buffer (Xvfb). From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb):

> Xvfb or X virtual framebuffer is a display server implementing the X11 display server protocol. In contrast to other display servers, Xvfb performs all graphical operations in memory without showing any screen output. From the point of view of the client, it acts exactly like any other X display server, serving requests and sending events and errors as appropriate. However, no output is shown. This virtual server does not require the computer it is running on to have a screen or any input device. Only a network layer is necessary.

On CentOS/RHEL, the `xorg-x11-server-Xvfb` package is available in the default repositories.

```
Available Packages
Name        : xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.17.2
Release     : 22.el7
Size        : 843 k
Repo        : base/7/x86_64
Summary     : A X Windows System virtual framebuffer X server.
URL         : http://www.x.org
License     : MIT and GPLv2
Description : Xvfb (X Virtual Frame Buffer) is an X server that is able to run on
            : machines with no display hardware and no physical input devices.
            : Xvfb simulates a dumb framebuffer using virtual memory.  Xvfb does
            : not open any devices, but behaves otherwise as an X display.  Xvfb
            : is normally used for testing servers.
```

To install it:

```
sudo yum -y install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
```

Once that was done, I could use the `xvfb-run` command to run my shell script in my environment.

```
[vagrant@localhost robotTests]$ xvfb-run ./run.sh
==============================================================================
Test
==============================================================================
Test <Redacted One>                                                   | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test <Redacted Two>                                                   | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test <Redacted Three>                                                 | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test                                                                  | PASS |
3 critical tests, 3 passed, 0 failed
3 tests total, 3 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /vagrant/robotTests/output.xml
Log:     /vagrant/robotTests/log.html
Report:  /vagrant/robotTests/report.html
```